# WinForms bad TabOrder with GroupBox, same tab order doubly assigned

Tags: winforms, groupbox, tab-ordering

I have a dialog with a group box inside (group box top right, tab order 9).

I try now to set the tab order over the whole dialog, including the group box. My changes inside the group box seem not to be reflected.

I also wonder since 9.0 and 9.1 seem to be doubly assigned, and that is exactly the place that is broken when I run the application and test.

The group box also only has one level of hierarchy below it, so all visible controls inside the group box are direct children of that group box.

The bad behavior is that the controls are not focused in the order I set in the WinForms designer, some are skipped.

[image]

Comment: It happens when you copy controls. It's normal, just use *View* → *Tab Order* and using the mouse pointer, click on the controls in order to assign new tab orders.

Comment: I never understood why winforms allows double assignment of taborder. Anyway, I always set the taborders of parents like groubox to values like 10, 20, 30 and all controls in them to something like 11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32...

Comment: I did assign the controls that interest me and thought that the designer would just assign new orders (at the end) for all controls I did not touch. Or do I really have to go through all 99 controls on the whole dialog each time?

Comment: The designer of visual studio is actually.... well bad compared to others. In order to not have to reassign all controls a new taborder I use the grouping like in my prior comment. I only need to reassign the taborder in the parentcontrol where something has changed, not all controls

Comment: It depends to the requirement. First of all, you need to set TabOrder for container controls. Then if the order of child controls is important to you, you need to set them as well. Also keep in mind, when two controls has the same tab index, the control with lower index in `Controls` collection will be the selection. You can see order of adding controls using *Document Outline* window.